# How to check for NDK_DEBUG flag in Android.mk?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

The following snippet is performing the "*** missing separator" message.

```
 ifeq($(NDK_DEBUG),1)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DP_DEBUG
 endif
```

How to properly check for NDK_DEBUG condition? Thank you.

Comment: How about `ifeq ($(APP_DEBUG),true)` ?

Comment: Thank you, this worked:
APP_DEBUG := $(strip $(NDK_DEBUG))
ifeq ($(APP_DEBUG),1)